# Changing push notification sound to a file not in the app bundle?

Tags: ios

Is is possible for a user to record a new sound to be used as the sound for the push notifications they receive from the app? In other words, is it possible to dynamically change the push notification sound using sound files uploaded externally, or do they have to be already located in the app bundle?

Answer (score 0):

From the Push notifications programming guide:

> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an application. The sound files must be in the main bundle of the client application.

So I would think that it's not possible, sorry.
The notifications will often be processed by the system while the app is closed, so I don't think there is a way to configure its behaviour beyond the basic features.